# Problema sobre certificados web cuando tengo 2 aplicaciones

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

buenos días.

Trabajo con:

- **Ubuntu 16.04**
- **Tomcat 8**
- **Java 1.8 (jdk)**

Estoy tratando de montar un sevidor **Tomcat** donde ejecuto dos aplicaciones:

A) Servidor **CAS** con seguridad ejecutándose en el **puerto 8443**

B) **Aplicación web** a la que redirige el *CAS*, esta se ejecuta en el **puerto 8080**

Lo que yo hago es:

1. Crear un certificado:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -validity 365 -keyalg RSA
   keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file autentia.csr
   ```
2. Una entidad certificadora con openssl:

   ```
   /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.sh -newca
   ```
3. Auto-firmar mi certificado con mi propia entidad:

   ```
   cp autentia.csr newreq.pem
   /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.sh -signreq
   cp newcert.pem autentiaCertFirmadoPorCA.pem
   ```
4. **Este certificado lo importo** tanto al fichero **.keystore**
   como al **cacerts de java**:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias autentiaCert -file autentiaCertFirmadoPorCA.pem 
   sudo keytool -import -alias autentiaCert -file autentiaCertFirmadoPorCA.pem -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts
   sudo cp /{RUTA}/.keystore /var/lib/tomcat8/lib/.keystore
   sudo chown -R tomcat8: /var/lib/tomcat8/lib/.keystore
   ```
5. Además configuro el archivo **server.xml** (solo la parte de
   conexión en el puerto 8443) de Tomcat asi:

   ```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true"
   SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" maxThreads="150"
   keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat8/lib/.keystore" 
   keystorePass="root12" truststorePass="changeit"
   truststoreFile="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/security/cacerts" />
   ```

**Finalmente** puedo acceder al **CAS**, pero al redirigirme a la otra aplicación me salta el siguiente error (La traza completa es mas larga):

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

Creo entender que no encuentra un certificado válido para la aplicación del **puerto 8080**, pero esta no tiene seguridad, por lo que no deberia de ser necesarío.

Pero pido ayuda para saber si estoy equivocado y en que me estoy equivocando.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo haces/a qué te refieres con la redirección?¿Haces un 302 Redirect? ¿Forward? ¿Haces un request desde CAS al otro webservice?

Comment: mediante filtros en la aplicación del puerto 8080, cuando no existe un tiquet, se redirige solo al CAS, hasta hay bien, me autentifico, y al regresar a la aplicación del puerto 8080 (lo hace de forma automatica), aparece ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me auto respondo.

Resulta que al instalar mediante "apt-get" Tomcat8, este no coje bien la versión de java. Probacando este error aunque indique en el fichero server.xml todos los archivos de certificados.

Para solucionarlo tan solo se debe cambiar la ruta de JAVA_HOME en el fichero correspondiente, en mi caso la ruta por defecto es:

```
/etc/default/tomcat8
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.